# I cannot get my array vertically into Google sheet with Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This code just returns the first item , A,  repeatedly

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('myspreadsheet').getActiveSheet();
var objarray = [["A"], ["B"], ["C"], ["D"]];
    var cell = sheet.getRange("B2:B5");
    cell.setValue(objarray);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `setValue` instead or `setValues`

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct. This will help others find it, should they be looking for something similar.